# Sum of all the sub-sequences of a number stored as a string

Tags: algorithm, subsequence

Find the sum of all the sub-sequences of a number stored as a string modulo (10^9)+7. The number can have up to N=2*(10^5) digits.

Example - If the string is 123, its sub-sequences are 1, 2, 3, 12, 23, 13, 123.
Ans = 1+2+3+12+23+13+123 = 177.

Comment: Have you thought about this problem? Where are your considerations?

Comment: Do you mean we only add numbers of order at most 10^9+7?

Answer (score 2):

Let `T(i)` be the sum of the first `i` digits of `N`, and write `N[k]` to mean the `k`th digit of `N`.

Then:

```
T(0) = 0
T(i) = T(i-1) + T(i-1) * 10 + N[k] * (2**i)
```

That's because the sums of subsequences of `T(i)` are the sums of subsequences of `T(i-1)` plus the sums of subsequences of `T(i-1)` each with the `k`th digit added to them. There's `2**i` of them, and multiplication by 10 commutes with the summation.

Simplifying, putting it into code, and doing arithmetic modulo `k` gives the relatively simple (and linear time in the number of digits) solution:

```
def subsequences(n, k):
    total = 0
    pow2 = 1
    for i, ds in enumerate(n):
        total = (11 * total + pow2 * int(ds)) % k
        pow2 = (2 * pow2) % k
    return total

print subsequences('123', 10**9 + 7)
```

Output:

```
177
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the question but here is some thought.

For n digit string number of subsequences is exponential so we cannot rely on brute force. But we can do it with dynamic programming. Let suppose F(i), denotes sum of all subsequences which their last element is the i th digit of string. We find the value of F(i+1) in O (i), and at the end to answer the question we output the summation F(1)+...+F(n).

Suppose i+1 th digit is j. Then

```
   F (i+1) =j+ (F (i)*10+ j)+(F (i-1)*10+ j)+...+(F (1)*10+ j)
               = (i+1)j+ 10 Sum F (z)  for 1<=z <= i
```

So final answer is ∑F (i)  for 1≤i≤ n.

This is maybe still not efficient enough as summation of big integers is already O (n), in each iteration we have O (n) such summations and there are O (n) iterations so leads to O (n^3), which is not very good, but way more better than exponential.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul Hankin. Your explanation is very good.Though I found out the algorithm later myself. Here's what I did. The approach is same.

```
static int mod = 1000000007;
public static long solve(String s) {
    long ans = 0;
    int n = s.length();
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        ans += (((Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i))*pow(11, n-i-1, mod))%mod)*pow(2, i, mod))%mod;
        ans %= mod;
    }
    return ans;
}
```